# trying to update a firebase document with update() but it not updating the document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-hook-form

i am trying to make a blog. I am working on an edit post functionality. When i call the `ref.update()` it says that the update worked but nothing is changed in the database in the following code.

Code

```
import AuthCheck from "../../components/AuthCheck";
import { firestore } from "../../lib/firebase";
import { useDocumentData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Editposts({}) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthCheck>
        <PostManager />
      </AuthCheck>
    </>
  );
}

const PostManager = () => {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;
  const postRef = firestore.collection("blogs").doc(slug);
  const [post] = useDocumentData(postRef);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {post && (
          <>
            <section>
              <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              <h4>{post.slug}</h4>
              <Postform
                postRef={postRef}
                defaultValues={post}
                preview={preview}
              />
            </section>
            <aside>
              <h3>Tools</h3>
              <button onClick={() => setPreview(!preview)}>
                {preview ? "Edit" : "Preview"}
              </button>
              <Link href={`/${post.slug}`}>
                <button className="btn btn-secondary">Live view</button>
              </Link>
              {/* <DeletePostButton postRef={postRef} /> */}
            </aside>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const Postform = ({ postRef, defaultValues, preview }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const updatePost = async ({ content, published }) => {
    await postRef.update({
      content,
      published,
    });

    reset({ content, published });

    toast.success("Post updated successfully!");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost)}>
      {preview && (
        <div className="card">
          <ReactMarkdown>{watch("content")}</ReactMarkdown>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className={preview ? `d-none`:``}>
        <textarea
          className='form-control'
          name="content"
          {...register("test", { required: true })}
        ></textarea>

        <fieldset>
          <input
            className="form-check-input"
            name="published"
            type="checkbox"
            {...register("test", { required: true })}
          />
          <label>Published</label>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

here when i submit the form, the popup says that the update was successful but when i cheeck the database, nothing changed. Here is an example image

[image: firebase and blog opened side by side]

Comment: Have you checked if you are using the Firestore emulator during testing? It might be writing it there instead of the production database.

Comment: how can i check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i find out the problem.
so the thing was i was following a tutorial and he was using 6.X.X which is the oudated version. So i went to the internet trying to find a solution and copy pasted a line of cide which is `{...register("test", { required: true })}` here i named the field value to 'test' instead of 'content' and that was causing the problem because there was no 'test' field to be updated. Hope someone finds this helpful